# How can I get a reference to the main view controller?

Tags: swift, cocoa

In one view, I make some changes the my core data database, which is displayed in a table in the main view controller. After making these changes, I want to table to `reloadData()` to display the new records I've added, but I can't find a way to get a reference to it to call the function.

I've tried this:

```
let window = NSApplication.shared.mainWindow
```

Thinking that if I could get the window, I might be able to get its view controller, but for some reason `window` is `nil`. I feel like this should be a straight-forward thing to do, but I can't find a way to do it.

If this isn't possible, or there's a better way to do what I'm trying to, that'd be useful too.

EDIT: Not sure why, but `NSApplication.shared.mainWindow` doesn't return `nil` anymore, but the window of the view I'm actually making the changes in (not the main `ViewController` window)

Comment: if let mainViewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow.rootViewController as? MainViewControler {
//Call method here.
}

Comment: `UIApplication` is for an iOS app, right?

Comment: Yup. Its for iOS app.

Comment: if let mainViewController = NSApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.contentViewController as? ManinViewController { 
//Invoke your method here
}

Comment: @Rohi my app is for macOS

Comment: i have commented again above.Could you check that once?

Comment: @Rohi looks like it might work, but I prefer SPatel's answer so I'll probably go with that one. Thanks though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use NotificationCenter, like below

```
class MainController:UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview:UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reload), name: NSNotification.Name("dataUpdated"), object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name("dataUpdated"), object: nil)
    }

    @objc func reload() {
        tableview.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Use

//after cordata changes, just post notification.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("dataUpdated"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to create a reference to the main view controller in `AppDelegate`

```
var mainViewController : MainViewController?
```

Set the property in `viewDidLoad` of `MainViewController`

```
override viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.mainViewController = self
}
```

Then you can reload the table view from everywhere

```
let appDelegate = NSApp.delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.mainViewController?.tableView.reloadData()
```